# SSLHandshakeException when connecting to Wiremock with my own self-signed cert

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I'm running a stand-alone instance of Wiremock for mocking in JUnit tests. This works fine with http and if I use the wiremock self-signed cert with the switch `--https-port 8443`. If I specify `--https-keystore server_keystore.jks` however, any attempt to communicate with Wiremock e.g `WireMock.reset();` throws a `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake`. Connecting to the admin page `https://localhost:9093/__admin/` in a browser shows a similar error about the connection being closed.

The keystore was generated as follows;

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -alias server -keypass secret -storepass secret -keystore server_keystore.jks
```

If I enable logging for all traffic in Wiremock I see;

```
Problem decoding network traffic
java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
```

I've added `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "server_keystore.jks");` in my calling code prior to attempting to communicate with Wiremock with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've set a password on your keystore you'll need to provide this to WireMock via the `--keystore-password` parameter.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention this but I have included the password argument.